Battery usage when iPad powered off?
I own an iPad Air (3rd generation, wifi/cellular).  Before powering it off, I set it to Airplane mode.  When I power it back it up, it show the correct time.  Does the time of day feature use some battery power even when powered off?  Does anything else use power on my iPad when it is powered off?  For example, does it use any power to monitor the power button?

Edit: The question How does an iOS device keep time when it is out of power? provides a partial answer to my question (it talks about the clock).
However I still would like to know if there are any other activities that use the battery when my iPad is powered off.

@IconDaemon That just confirms that it uses the battery for the clock, it doesn't answer whether there are other components that also use the battery.

@IconDaemon Thanks for the link to a related question.  I have updated my question.

There is also "power usage" from "non activity": the battery will self-discharge when it is not in use, which will also lead to power loss. It's a normal phenomenon.

The firmware is always working on any Apple device with M1 or Apple Silicon or arm chips.  It’s the same story, the actual watchOS, iPadOS, tvOS (but since they don’t have batteries, there’s never a true shutdown), iOS, macOS is not running at all when the device is powered off. Just the clock, networking, USB, charging and screen run in lowest power modes.

See my comment https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/87581/5472 - if you want to get this reopened, it will need an edit to ask one question clearly. But the answer is everything on the firmware is always running and it uses less energy in standby than the battery loses naturally over time when it’s not charging. It’s literally a rounding error on the batteries on Apple devices.
